# How Yocto handle multiple .bbappend with the same name?

Tags: inheritance, append, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

For example, I am having `meta-A/test.bbappend` and `meta-B/test.bbappend` files.

`meta-A/test.bbappend priority 10`

```
SAME_VAR = "a"
```

`meta-B/test.bbappend priority 5`

```
SAME_VAR = "b"
DIFF_VAR = "b"
```

I think `SAME_VAR` will be `"a"` but what about `DIFF_VAR`?
Would `meta-B/test.bbappend` be completely ignored due to lower priority?

Comment: They will all be applied in the priority order.

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk Would `DIFF_VAR = "b"` exists?

Comment: `bitbake recipe_name -e | grep DIFF_VAR` and check yourself

Answer (score 0):

Every layer has its own priority defined in `conf/layer.conf` as `BBFILE_PRIORITY` variable. Priority of the layer defines in which order `.bbappend` files will append on original `.bb`.

You can check all layers in your project with

> bitbake-layers show-layers

and you will also see the priorities.

Comment: what about multiple bbappend files for a specific recipe within one layer?

Comment: It is determined the same in `conf/layer.conf` or `conf/layer.conf.append`.
The thing is that you can write something like this in layer.conf `*.bbappend` for some particular directory. In that case I am not sure, but I guess that files will be appended in alphabetical order.